# Calling ssh from powerbuilder with ssh private key

Tags: windows, unix, powerbuilder, ssh-keys

I need to ssh Unix server for reading a file from server from windows application built on Powerbuilder..  I hav a private key in local and added to pub key in server. Please suggest some idea with freeware but not with paid shareware.

Answer (score 0):

I have not realized it but you could try it with putty in its command line mode, I hope it helps:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

http://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/putty/putty-how-to-start-a-ssh-session-from-the-command-line/